# ET_GPBufferPolylines doesn't work

Tags: arcpy, dissolve, et-geowizards

i have a problem with an ET GeoWizard function or maybe just a basic syntax problem. I need to use a script that someome else wrote and which does things that i do not completely understand unfortunately.
So what is the matter:
Here is the part from my script that fails:

```
# Process: FeatureClass To FeatureClass (XX)
arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(water01_l_layer, output_polyline_folder, 'water01_l_XX.shp', '"OBJEKT_NR" = XX', "OBJEKT_NR \"OBJEKT_NR\" true true false 19 Double 0 0 ,First,#,water01_l_layer,OBJEKT_NR,-1,-1;RAUHEIT \"RAUHEIT\" true true false 19 Double 0 0 ,First,#,water01_l_layer,RAUHEIT,-1,-1;BUFFER \"BUFFER\" true true false 19 Double 0 0 ,First,#,water01_l_layer,BUFFER,-1,-1", "")
# Process: ET Buffer Polylines (XX)
arcpy.ET_GPBufferPolylines(output_polyline_folder + "\\water01_l_XX.shp", output_polygon_folder + "\\water01_b_XX.shp", 'BUFFER', '#', 'Both', 'Flat', 'false')
# Process: Dissolve (XX)
arcpy.Dissolve_management(output_polygon_folder + "\\water01_b_XX.shp", output_polygon_folder + "\\water01_d_XX.shp", 'OBJEKT_NR;RAUHEIT', '#', 'SINGLE_PART', 'DISSOLVE_LINES')
# Process: ET Clean Polygon (XX)
if arcpy.management.GetCount(output_polygon_folder + "\\water01_d_XX.shp")[0] == "0":
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(output_polygon_folder + "\\water01_d_XX.shp", output_dissolve_folder + "\\water01_c_XX.shp")
else:
    arcpy.ET_GPCleanPolygon(output_polygon_folder + "\\water01_d_XX.shp", output_dissolve_folder + "\\water01_c_XX.shp", '0,2', '#')
```

For the basics: the folders are defined further up in the script. They exist and they work for other lines before.
If I get that right, the first line (FeatureClasstoFeatureClass) saves the layer "water01_l_layer" in a shapefile "water01_l_XX.shp" which works apparently. I can find that file in the supposed folder.

Now, the next line fails. It doesn't show an error message it just doesn't create the file (water01_b_XX.shp), which causes the next step (Dissolve_management) so crash with the error, that the file "water01_b_XX.shp" doesn't exist or is not valid.

What i checked:

1. the file "water01_l_XX.shp" exists and contains a field "BUFFER" which contains double values. The delimiter is a "," - can this cause a problem? does it need to be a "."?
2. I created the file "water01_b_XX.shp" myself by buffering the layer with the given field "BUFFER" and saved it in the supposed folder. Instead of hopping to the next step, the script crashed again at the same line stating that the file doesn't exist. My file indeed had vanished from the folder.

Is there an easy way to run my script in debug mode?

This is my first time using ArcGIS and i'm not really familiar with python. I'm not allowed to install any software on the workstation i'm using.

Comment: Is this the ET Geowizards tool? https://www.ian-ko.com/ET_GeoWizards/ETGW12UG_WEB/etgw/bufferPolylines.htm you are using?

Comment: Yes, this is the correct tool.

Comment: According to the help file Mapperz referenced above, the third parameter should be "Buffer Side" with valid options of Left, Right and Both. Your third parameter is 'BUFFER'

Comment: i think that depends on the function. As I use the "ET_GPBufferPolylines" function i referenced this file: https://www.ian-ko.com/ET_GeoWizards/UserGuide/bufferPolylines.htm which makes the third parameter the buffer distance, which in my case is taken from the field "BUFFER". But i see now, that this syntax is not described in the file provided by Mapperz. I'm sorry for the confusion.